# Is Promise.resolve(dispatch(null)) is possible in redux?

Tags: react-redux

In redux Promise.resolve(dispatch(null)) is possible?

I am trying to dispatch null in order to create an action ? Will this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in redux. As redux documentation says, an action can only be dispatched when it is a plain object and type of action is not undefined.

Here is the code snippet for dispatch function in redux/src/createStore.js file.

```
function dispatch(action) {
    if (!isPlainObject(action)) {
      throw new Error(
        'Actions must be plain objects. ' +
        'Use custom middleware for async actions.'
      )
    }

    if (typeof action.type === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(
        'Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. ' +
        'Have you misspelled a constant?'
      )
    }

    if (isDispatching) {
      throw new Error('Reducers may not dispatch actions.')
    }

    try {
      isDispatching = true
      currentState = currentReducer(currentState, action)
    } finally {
      isDispatching = false
    }

    const listeners = currentListeners = nextListeners
    for (let i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
      const listener = listeners[i]
      listener()
    }

    return action
  }
```

Instead of dispatching like the way you suggested, a better implementation would be

`Promise.resolve(dispatch({ type: 'YOUR_SAMPLE_ACTION_TYPE', data: null }))`

I hope it helps. Thanks!